# unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: magento2

#### Summary (*)

Magento 2, Version 2.2.8 started throwing 500 error after update.

#### Examples (*)

Error logs

```
Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): The specified \"/home/.../public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php.27337\" file could not be written Warning!file_put_contents(/home/.../public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php.27337): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Class Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only. at /home/.../public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:135)"} []
```

#### Proposed solution

Ran the following commands, compile and cleared cache.

```
 chmod -R 0777 generated

 find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;

 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

 find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

 find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

 find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

 chmod 777 ./app/etc

 chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

 rm -rf pub/static/*

 rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache

 find ./pub/media/catalog -type f -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

Comment: run upgrade, then redeploy static contents, then apply chmod then check it should work

Comment: Have you checked the permission for generated folder? Please share the screenshot in your Magento root folder by running ll command

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Mitrajsinh vaghela's first Solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perform This Command In DataBase :-**

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'Your/Site/Url' WHERE config_id = '5';

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'Your/Site/Url' WHERE config_id = '6';
```

**Please Follow This Step:-**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/ var/ pub/ app/
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. However, applying those commands didn't sold the problem. Still getting 500 error. Screenshot here:  http://prntscr.com/n6744r

Comment: check  base url in core_config_data table

Comment: Hi @Mitrajsinh I just checked the core_config_data table and it looked really weird to me because I couldn't see the site's URL. Here's the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/n6hepw

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thanks Mitrajsinh vaghela! Your first Solution solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all enable error log & uncomment this below line from the file `app/bootstrap.php` 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Apply r/w permission as per [Magento Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/trouble/readiness/tshoot_rc_perms.html).

After check error it might be possible from third party extension are giving error.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Mitrajsinh vaghela's first Solution solved the problem.